# Learning how to code: Why is my code not working JavaScript/CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, event-handling, dom-events

I'm trying to toggle CSS stylesheets by clicking one of two buttons. However, my code isn't working. Not sure what I'm missing. I'm working with a separate index.html that I cannot modify and a separate js file.

Here is my code below. I'm getting a TypeError: cannot read properties of null (reading addEventListener'.

Index.html file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Assignment 4</title>  <link id="styleSheet" href="styleA.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  
    <script src="styler.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <button id="styleA" type="submit">Use styleA</button>
        <button id="styleB" type="submit">Use styleB</button>
    </form>
    <article>
        <h1>OSU Beaver Store - CS 290 Version</h1>
            <p>Catering to All Your Beaver-Gear Needs</p>
        <div>
            <table>
                <caption>Our Most Popular Items</caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Orange Beaver Polo</td>
                        <td>49.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3 Pack Beaver Socks</td>
                        <td>28.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Orange Beavers Hat</td>
                        <td>32.50</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Waterproof Jacket</td>
                        <td>65.55</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            <div id="beaver-store">
                <a href="https://osubeaverstore.com/">Visit The Official Beaver Store</a>
            </div>
    </article>


    <div>
        <span id="o">O</span><span id="s">S</span><span id ="u">U</span>
    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

JS File:

```
"use strict";
let aLink= document.querySelector("link");
const aButton = document.getElementById("styleA");
const bButton = document.getElementById("styleB");

function changeToA(){
    preventDefault();
    aLink.setAttribute('href', 'styleB.css');
}

 function changeToB(){
    aLink.setAttribute('href', 'styleB.css');
}

 aButton.addEventListener("click",changeToA);
 bButton.addEventListener("click",changeToB);
```

***Update:

I figured it out. Needed to have another event listener for DOMloadedcontent.

Comment: is your code running too early? i.e. before the DOM is loaded? Do the elements with those ID's exist? try moving the javascript to just before `</body>` see if that improves your problem

Comment: `preventDefault` doesn’t exist. Please read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Comment: Put the script tag inside the body at the end or add defer to it like: `<script src="styler.js" defer></script>`